# Why do I have occasional Jackett errors with Qbittorrrent

Tags: jackett

I use Qbittorrent to share software projects with friends. I am sure that there are other self-hosted alternatives to GitHub, but that's not the question here.

I sometimes get Jackett errors like this:

[image]

but, only occasionally, not always. My Jackett config is fine. I have checked it repeatedly.

Any idea why this is happening & what I can do about it?

Comment: (1) Update all search plugins. (2) Check "Use proxy only for torrents" under *Connection > Proxy Server*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been seeing those intermittent Jackett errors too for at least 3 years now in qbittorrent.
Seems to be some kind of time-out issue were the Jackett server takes too long to respond to a search request.
(Or delivers the first part of the response and then takes too long to provide subsequent parts.)

There is nothing you can do about this, besides configuring qBittorrent no to use Jackett anymore.

Comment: I don't suppose that you know of any good alternative?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I don't, but I never looked very hard. I don't really need it anyway so I just configure QB not to use it. What is irritating me most is that after just about any QB update ALL plugins get re-enabled. Including Jackett. It is on the QB bugtracker the plugin config doesn't always stick after an update but it is very low prio. I don't expect it ever to be fixed.